# Python- Getting a random object from a list based on attribute

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

For a python role-playing game, I am trying to randomly grab a monster from a list of objects based on the player  object's attribute 'self.level'.
Eventually, I will have over 100 unique monsters.
Currently I have something like,

```
MONSTERS =[Kobold,... Skeleton,... Orc,.. Minotaur,.. Spector,... Wraith,... Balrog, Dragon]
monster_cls = random.choice(MONSTERS)
```

I want the 'monster.challenge_rating' to correspond roughly to the player's level- within a level or two. Currently I am using:

```
monster.challenge_rating = player_1.level + random.randint(0, 2)
```

Originally, I was simply upping the monster.challenge_rating of each monster to correspond to the player_1.level
But, in order to add depth to the game, I was planning on making a list of objects for each challenge rating level, like,

```
monster_cr_1 = [rat, spider, flying snake..]
monster_cr_2 = [giant rat, giant spider...]
monster_cr_3 = [Kobold, Skeleton.....]
monster_cr_4 = [Drow, Orc, Mummy, Ghoul]
..
monster_cr_20 = [Balrog, Red Dragon, Kraken,...]
```

I don't want to do:

```
if player_1.level == 1:
    random.choice(monster_cr_1)
if player_1.level == 2:
    random.choice(monster_cr_2)...
```

The maximum player level will be 20, so I know I will end up with many, many if statements.  So, I attempted to grab it by appending the attribute to the end of a string. Something like:

```
monster = "monster_cr_", player_1.level
monster_cls = random.choice(monster)
```

But, I get all kinds of str object not callable and type errors.
Is there a syntax that makes this possible?
Is there a better way to do what I want that remains somewhat 'human readable' ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary.

```py
import random


monsters = {
    1: ['rat', 'spider', 'flying snake'],
    2: ['giant rat', 'giant spider', 'kobold'],
    3: ['drow', 'orc', 'mummy']
}

player_level = 1
monster = random.choice(monsters[player_level])
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! A dictionary full of lists; brilliant. I needed to get rid of the single quotes, since each item will be an actual class object, not a string... But it works perfectly. I really appreciate the answer. It is like putting another tool into my toolbox.